# How to delay Userform TextBox1_Change() triggering until entering multiple characters singly is complete?

Tags: vba, triggers, textbox, userform

I have a macro which uses entered value from TextBox1. If a value is given to TextBox1 as a whole, the code runs fine. If a value is entered character by character (scanned with a handheld barcode scanner) the code: TextBox1_Change() triggers on every character.

How do I make the macro start only when the whole value is entered (the length of the value may differ)? Maybe there is a way to catch the barcode scanners ENTER?

Extra buttons to manually trigger the code are not an option.

Also asked [here](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1340803-vba-userform-textbox1_change-triggering.html#post5469795)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved with this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: For what it's worth, that code is doing exactly nothing at all.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different event triggers for a text box. TextBox1_Exit would be the one you're looking for. It triggers when the user clicks away from the text box or closes the userform.

Change the name of the Sub to TextBox1_Exit() and see if the behavior is what you're looking for.

If that isn't it then try [Application.OnTime](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/delay-a-macro.html). You can delay the macro execution by a second giving the barcode scanner plenty of time to finish inputting the text.

```
Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "MacroName"
```